# Let $\text{A}$ be a nonsingular $\textit{n}\times\textit{n}$ matrix, and let $\textit{B}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Show that $ B_1 = \{\textbf{Av}| \textbf{v} \in B\} $ is also a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n.$

I apologize for my informality, but I would really like some feedback as to whether I am using the correct reasoning.

To begin, I noticed that this set $ B_1$ should contain an $\textit{n}\times 1$ vector. So, this means that I need to prove that this vector is linearly independent and spans $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Since no component of $\textbf{v}$ is $0$ because it is linearly independent, and $\textbf{A}$ only has the trivial solution for a homogeneous system, then any $\textbf{Av}$ should be linearly independent. Because the dimensions of $\textit{B}_1$ are the same as $\mathbb{R}^n$, then it is a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can formalize this using rank-nullity. Since $A$ is non-singular, $A(v)\ =\ 0\  \textbf{iff}\ v\ = \ 0$. By rank-nullity, the rank of $Av$ is $n$, so $Av$ is an n-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, so it is $\mathbb R^n$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $B=\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$, so $B_1=\{Av_1,\cdots,Av_n\}$.

Since $B_1$ has n vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$, we can either show that $B_1$ is linearly independent or that it spans $\mathbb{R^n}$.

To show that $B_1$ is linearly independent,

show that $c_1\big(Av_1\big)+\cdots+c_n\big(Av_n\big)=0 \implies c_1=0, \cdots, c_n=0$
using the fact that A is nonsingular.